# ROC curve for decision trees using rocr package

Tags: r, classification, data-mining, decision-tree

I use `rpart` package to develop my tree and predict the model. Finally to plot the ROC curve I try to use the `rocr` package. Apologies for not reproducing it with inbuilt data set was not able to. Please find the link for the csv i have use:

[Wine Quality.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Ev2c2CeM2cTklFVG1SYUFyVGs)

Now please see my code:

```
#setting up data
data<- read.csv(file.choose())
quality_binary <- ifelse(wine_quality >5,"high","low")
data <- data.frame(data,quality_binary)

#re shuffling the data
set.seed(9850)
g <- runif(nrow(data))
datar<- data[order(g),]
#removing the wine quality column since it has to be predicted
datar <- datar[-12]

library(rpart)  
library(rpart.plot)
library(cvTools) 
library(caret)
library(tree)

k <- 10 # setting the value for 10 fold validation 

folds <- cvFolds(NROW(datar), K=k)
datar$holdoutpred <- rep(0,nrow(datar))

for(i in 1:k){

train <- datar[folds$subsets[folds$which != i], ] #training set
validation <- datar[folds$subsets[folds$which == i], ] #validation set

#tree model
tree_model_rpart_gini = rpart(quality_binary~.,data = train,
        parms = list(split = "information"), method  = "class")
rpart.plot(tree_model_rpart_gini,type = 3,extra = 101)

#prediction
pred_model_rpart_gini <- predict(tree_model_rpart_gini,   
newdata=validation, type="class")

datar[folds$subsets[folds$which == i], ]$holdoutpred <-   
pred_model_rpart_gini

}

#plotting ROC curve

library(ROCR)
 pred1 <- prediction(predict(datar$pred_model_rpart_gini),   
 datar$quality_binary)
 perf1 <- performance(pred1,"tpr","fpr")
 plot(perf1)
```

And my error is:

```
pred1 <- prediction(predict(datar$pred_model_rpart_gini),   
datar$quality_binary)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. Try creating a tree using some built in data set such as `mtcars` and post your code here.

Comment: How to post code in the comment

Comment: Edit your question instead.

Comment: **Never** post code in comment. Use the [edit] button.

Comment: Actually when i tried practicing it using "iris" , it worked. so can i post my full original code?

Comment: Tried creating it with a inbuilt data set getting different error:( totally confused. can i post my original code

Comment: As David said, you should add a (1) minimal example that (2) reproduces the error on copy->paste->run. The error message seems to tell you that `tree_model` is of type factor, not of class rpart. So probably something went wrong in your `rpart` call...?

Comment: Your argument in `predict()` doesn't seem to make sense. Try `pred1 <- prediction(predict(tree_model, datar, type='prob')[,2], datar$quality_binary)`. Or post a reproducible example.

Comment: I have posted the code in copy-> reproduce format. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. However, I get `object 'wine_quality' not found` in line 3.

Comment: In your previous copy of this question your code still worked better? Now you've broken it completely...  [Decision tree classification and accuracy estimation using 10 fold cross validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400102/decision-tree-classification-and-accuracy-estimation-using-10-fold-cross-validat)

Comment: i have renamed it in all places i guess

Comment: Reproducible example should server as a model of how to structure your data to make it work. I will vote for a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datar$pred_model_rpart_gini` is `NULL` i.e. undefined.

Ou probably meant to use `pred_model_rpart_gini` (no `datar$`)  instead?

Comment: Sorry, don get you. Could u pl explain.

Comment: You have a copy&paste error there, that you need to fix. If you rename things in one place, you have to rename them everywhere.